# SKAction.reach doesn't orient to child node that has moved

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I do apologize up front for this question as I am very new to Swift, SpriteKit and game development in general.

I am playing around with the inverse kinematic functionality in SpriteKit. Specifically, I am trying to use the SKAction.reach action to orient a node to point to another.

The challenge I am having is when I want to orient to a child node. Specifically, I have this very simply code that I am playing with inside of my SKScene class:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // Already defined: parent_a, parent_b, child_a, child_b (all SKNode)
    // with child_a having parent of parent_a
    // and child_b having parent of parent_b

    // Purposely only change the coordinate of the parent item
    parent_b?.position = CGPoint(x:parent_b!.position.x,y: parent_b!.position.y + 50)

    // WHen this line is uncommented, then I get the WRONG behaviour: the "A" elements point at the original location
    child_a?.run(SKAction.reach(to: child_b!, rootNode: parent_a!, duration: 0.5))
    // But this line "works" CORRECTly; the "A" elements continue to point up at the moving object (note: I really want to orient to the child)
    //child_a?.run(SKAction.reach(to: parent_b!, rootNode: parent_a!, duration: 0.5))
}
```

Essentially, when I tap the screen, I move the parent_b node up the screen. Visually, the child_b node *also* moves up. If I have the first line in use, my "A" object points at the original location for the "B" objects. If I use the second line, then "A" will orient and point at "B" as I move it higher and higher. My goal is to have "A" orient to "B" at all times.

I'm not sure I understand why this happens or how to get the behaviour I want. I can understand that the "child" objects have their positions relative to their parents, but I don't know how to get the child objects to orient to one another.

Many thanks for any and all help!